# Why there is a difference between the output of 'echo $VAR | wc -c' and 'echo ${#VAR}'?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, echo, wc

I'm working on a Bash script and the length of the string contained in a certain variable is one of my conditions. The current string is `W5u7TBTzF17GGFV8DBJHvgAAAAI`. Initially I've count the string length by the help of `wc -c`:

```
$ VAR='W5u7TBTzF17GGFV8DBJHvgAAAAI'; echo "$VAR" | wc -c
28
```

But my script condition `[[ ${#VAR} -eq 28 ]]` never pass. Then I decided to count the characters on by one. Indeed the string length is 27 characters, also the value of `${#VAR}` is 27:

```
$ echo "${#VAR}"
27
```

So I'm in wondering - where does this difference come from?

Comment: This `echo -n ${VAR} | wc -c` give `27`, so newline character is there

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, probably this should be the answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the way `echo` works. Now do

```
echo koko
```

You get

```
georgek@georgek-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ echo koko
koko
```

But do `echo -n koko` and you get

```
georgek@georgek-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ echo -n koko
kokogeorgek@georgek-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$
```

So `wc` is capturing the `newline character` too. Use

```
echo -n "${VAR}" | wc -c
```

To get the desired result. The `echo` command will add the `newline` character, so that gets counted too. To remove this and get the real count use the `-n` option.

Comment: Almost right, up until the last part. [Don't use `echo -n`. Just use `printf '%s'`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/) (And of course don't forget to quote `"${VAR}"`.)

Comment: We can't win it all can we, thanks for the heads up! @wchargin :-)